# Basic properties of nontrivial zeros of an L function

Tags: number-theory

Let $L(s,\chi)$ be the L function associated to primitive character $\chi$ to the modulus
$q$. And let $\rho$ be a non trivial zero. It says on p83, "Multiplicative Number Theory" by Davenport that
"for a complex $\chi$, the zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ are still symmetric about the line
$\sigma = 1/2$, since $1 - \bar{\rho} = \rho'$ ." I am a bit confused about this sentence.

Does this sentence mean $L(\rho, \chi) = 0$, then $L(1-\rho, \chi)=0$
(by symmetric about the line $\sigma = 1/2$)?
or something else? I was guessing it means something else, but it 
would be great if someone could clarify this point for me.
Thank you!

Comment: You may want to move this question to MathOverflow.

Comment: @Michael I don't see why...

Comment: What else could it mean?

Comment: Tom, MathOverflow is more visited by practising mathematicians who are more familiar with $L$-functions.

Comment: @Michael there are plenty of mathematicians here, too, and this is not really a research-level problem -- Davenport is a GTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is that if $L(\rho, \chi) = 0$ then $L(1-\overline{\rho}, \chi) = 0$ as well.

This should follow from the functional equation (technically the functional equation relates $L(s, \chi)$ and $L(1-s, \overline{\chi})$, but playing around with complex conjugates should get you what you want, I think).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was starting to suspect maybe this was the case!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on $L$ functions, but in complex analysis, if we state that 2 numbers are symmetric about the line $\sigma = 1/2$, then what we mean is that if $a+ib$ is one of the pair, then the other one would be $(1-a)+bi$. In other words, if you were to plot them on the complex plane, they would lie on opposite sides of the vertical line $\sigma=1/2$ and be equidistant from the line. The same sort of result would apply to any roots of the zeta function which did not lie on the critical line - if there are any!

Comment: Thank you for the comment! That's what I thought first too, but I couldn't deduce it, so I decided to ask..